# Determining whether a change in ranking is statistically significant

Tags: ranking, group-differences

I have two populations, A `(n=48)` and B `(n=19)`. Both took a pre-test, after which B performed an intervention. Both A and B took a post-test which was not the same as the pre-test. It now appears that, while A were originally performing better than B, B is now performing better than A. I want to determine whether this change in performance is significant. I can do this by ranking the scores on each test (using `RANK.AVG` in Excel, which gives me a rank with an averaged rank for ties) and comparing the difference in the average ranking of each group.

Here's what I found:

```
Average pre-test rank A: 31.9
Average pre-test rank B: 39.7

Average post-test rank A: 34.8
Average post-test rank B: 32.1
```

This indicates to me that:

```
Average rank change A: -2.8
Average rank change B: +7.7
```

I take this to mean that, possibly due to the intervention, B have gone up in the rankings across the population (on average) while A have dropped. Is there any better way to be investigating this? How can I tell if this change in ranking is significant?

Comment: Could you explain why the pre-test results might have any relevance to the question whether "group B is now performing better than group A"? Your focus on pre-test results suggests you're actually trying to address a different question, which makes your question ambiguous.

Comment: The reason I have a pre-test is to give me a starting benchmark, otherwise I would not be able to tell if B have improved after the intervention, or if they've just been performing better than A all along.

Comment: But that concerns a completely different question than the one you have formulated.

Comment: I am sorry, you will have to help me see how. I want to determine if a change in ranking is significant - how can I do that without a starting point to change from?

Comment: "I want to try and determine if group B is now performing better than group A" is an absolute comparison against how the groups are performing now, regardless of how they might have performed previously.  Perhaps instead of comparing *performances* you wish to compare *changes* in performance?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I tried to get at this at the end of the question but it is not clear in the opening statement. I will adjust my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Wilcoxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) approach to the matter. This is a test for paired samples (pretest and post-test), although you will have to compute is separately for each group. But potentially, you will be able to say that group B improved significantly while group A didn't.